# Mongo import: file with multiple update queries for different "_id"

Tags: mongodb

I've db name `test` and collection `map` and i have update queries in my file like below

`db.map.save({_id:"test1",item: "apple", value: null, hunt: "parallel", record: true})
db.map.save({_id:"test2",item: null, value: "high", hunt: "parallel", record: true})
db.map.save({_id:"test3",item: "orange", value: "high", hunt: "parallel", record: true})
db.map.save({_id:"test4",item: "apple", value: "medium", hunt: "parallel", record: true})
db.map.save({_id:"test5",item: "orange", value: "small", hunt: "parallel", record: true})`

I can copy paste in mongo terminal and update, but i've some 100+ update queries.
what file format should save and how to dump it to my db? If any one has better idea please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your file calling the shell, just like this:

```
mongo server:port/database yourfile.js
```

There are several other ways to do this, check this link on docs for more info:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Comment: Thanks this worked. My mongodb (MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12) runs in localhost on default port so even `mongo database myfile.js` worked